# XNA Confusion about 2d Rectangle arrays

Tags: c#, xna, tile

I'm making a tiled strategy game alhoug it doesn't even resemble that in complexity. however, I ran into something i can't figure out myself. it should make the tile a click red and if i click it again it should make it normal again. but what it does is: in the first 4 or so tiles it makes everythinng red on the opposide sideflipped verticly,, but that should be fixable by reversing and x and y value. however after the fourth tile everything just get's placed on a random place(or as it seems atleast).i really can't figure it out myself and i have rewritten it from scratch 3 times already. I would be really thankfull if a more experienced (or less experienced is also okay) programmer could point me to my problem

My code(chopped up in chunks of releveance ):

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
baseLayer.LoadContent("TextFile1.txt");

standardTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tiles/Grass/GrassTile1");
        selectRects = new Rectangle[(int)baseLayer.MapDimensions.X, (int)baseLayer.MapDimensions.Y];
        while (j<baseLayer.MapDimensions.Y)
        {
            while (i < baseLayer.MapDimensions.X)
            {
                selectRects[i, j] = new Rectangle(i * standardTexture.Width, j * standardTexture.Height,
                    standardTexture.Width, standardTexture.Height);
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        while(j<baseLayer.MapDimensions.Y)
        {
            while(i<baseLayer.MapDimensions.X)
            {
                if (standardCheck.Click(selectRects[i, j], mouseState, prevMouseState)) 
                {
                    if (colorArray[i, j] != Color.White)
                        colorArray[i, j] = Color.White;
                    else
                        colorArray[i, j] = Color.Red;
                }
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
```

and my main drawing class(a litle bigger):

```
  public class LoadMap
  {

    {
        get { return map; }
        set { map = value; }
    }
    public Vector2 MapDimensions
    {
        get { return dimensions; }
        set { dimensions = value; }
    }
    public LoadMap()
    {
        lineindex = 0;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D[] maptexture,Color[,] color)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < dimensions.X; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimensions.Y; j++)
            {
                if (map[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(maptexture[0],
                        new Vector2(j * maptexture[0].Width, i * maptexture[0].Height), color[i,j]);
                }
                if (map[i, j] == 2)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(maptexture[1],
                        new Vector2(j * maptexture[0].Width, i * maptexture[0].Height), color[i, j]);
                }
                if (map[i, j] == 3)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(maptexture[2],
                        new Vector2(j * maptexture[0].Width, i * maptexture[0].Height), color[i, j]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Unrelated question. In your LoadContent, why are you using a While with a j++, instead of just a for-loop? This is literally the type of loop that a for-loop was invented for.

Comment: one simple answer: a (probably bad) habbit. I started using while loops first and I do use for loops sometimes, but i Always feel like it's a little messier